# Compiling error with Sparse Modeling Software

Tags: c++, c, matlab, sparse-matrix, mex

I'm trying to use [SPAM](http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/downloads.html) for Matlab. I downloaded the zip file with Matlab interface. Firstly, I run the following command:

```
mex -setup
```

and it showed:

[image]

After that,I run "compile.m" script, but I got the error below:

[image]

I tried to change the compiler with "mex","clang" and "gcc" but nothing solves the issue. Can you help me fix it?

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using, and what version of Xcode do you have?  Only certain versions of Xcode are compatible depending on what version of MATLAB you're using.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Matlab R2014a and Xcode 7

Comment: Xcode 7 is not compatible with R2014a.  You need to modify your MEX properties to get this to work.  See this MathWorks post here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/243868-mex-can-t-find-compiler-after-xcode-7-update-r2015b

Comment: Thanks, actually I modified it already, but the error keeps appearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find a solution. I'm using Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite) and some parameters in the script "compile.m" have to be compatible with each other.

```
compiler='mex'

blas='builtin'

use_multithread=false

add_flag=' -mmacosx-version-min=10.7'
```

And there will be issue with conversion in the file "mexSimpleGroupTree.cpp" and we need to change the line 33 to:

```
mwSize cdims[] = {static_cast<mwSize>(n)};
```

That's all for me to make it compile